# MVC Unobtrusive Validation. How to display validation message with toastr message plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I have simple Ajax form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SignUpForFree", null, new AjaxOptions()
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }, new { id = "signup-form" }))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        <input type="submit" value="CREATE FREE ACCOUNT" onclick="customSubmit()"/>
    }
```

and JS which validate the form and if it's not valid - displays messages in message window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function customSubmit() {
            var form = $("#signup-form");
            if (!ValidateForm(form))
                return;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "@Url.Action("SignUpForFree")",
                data: form.serialize()
            });
        }
    </script>
function ValidateForm(form) {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    var validator = form.validate();
    if (!form.valid()) {
        //some code here to display error message
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But when I submit the form - I have 2 submit which happens one by one. 
How I can prevent 2nd submit or how I can override standard validation process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer for my question.
This is the form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SignUpForFree", null, new AjaxOptions()
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }, new { id = "signup-form" }))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        <input type="submit" value="CREATE FREE ACCOUNT"/>
    }
```

And this how to hook even when validation fails and add your-own handler for this as additional to exists one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#signup-form').bind('invalid-form.validate', function (form, validator) {
                showErrorMessagesOnValidate(validator.errorList);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And this is function which will show toastr.js messages with validation errors:

```
showErrorMessagesOnValidate = function(errors) {
    if (!errors)
        return;
    var toastrObj = {
        ToastMessages: []
    };
    errors.forEach(function(item) {
        var label = $(item.element.labels[0]).text();
        var msg = {
            Title: label,
            Message: item.message,
            Type: "Warning"
        };
        toastrObj.ToastMessages.push(msg);
    });
    displayMessages(toastrObj);
}
function displayMessages(toastrObj) {
    $.each(toastrObj.ToastMessages, function (idx, msg) {
        toastr[msg.Type.toLowerCase()](msg.Message, msg.Title, {});
    });
}
```

Thanks for article from CodeProject [Modify jQuery validation settings using MVC unobtrusive validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/539167/Modify-jQuery-validation-settings-using-MVC-unobtr)

Answer (score 0):

I did not test the code and so not sure whether it compiles or not. But the below should give you an idea. I also assume you have already included toastr.js in your bundleconfig.cs

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SignUpForFree", null, new AjaxOptions()
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "customSubmitSuccess(data)"
    }, new { id = "signup-form" }))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        <input type="submit" value="CREATE FREE ACCOUNT" />
    }

<script type="text/javascript">

        function customSubmitSuccess(result) {
            if (result.success) {
                // do something when it is success
            } else {
                var formErrors = [];
                $.each(result.errors, function (key, val) {
                    var container = $('span[data-valmsg-for="' + key + '"]');
                    container.removeClass("field-validation-valid").addClass("field-validation-error");
                    container.html(val[val.length - 1].ErrorMessage);

                    formErrors.push(key + "    :  " + val[val.length - 1].ErrorMessage);

                });
                toastr.error(formErrors.join(", "));
            }
        }

        $(function () {
            //allow validation framework to parse DOM
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @sam for your help but it doesn't work for me. OnSuccess will happens after form submit to server side and validation fails there (this.ModelState.IsValid). On this case I already know how to show toastr messages. But I use client side validation and it validate form before submit.